# if statement with dynamic variable names

Tags: bash, shell

I created dynamic variables.

```
for (( c=1; c<=2; c++ ))
do  
   eval "prev$c=$number";
done
```

`prev1`, `prev2`

```
for (( c=1; c<=2; c++ ))
do  
   eval "current$c=$number";
done
```

`current1`, `current2`

if I have the variables

`$prev1` is `1`
`$prev2` is `2`
`$current1` is `1`
`$current2` is `3`

How do I compare inside a loop with if? Below is wrong, could someone correct the syntax? Thanks in advance.

```
for (( c=1; c<=2; c++ ))
do  
 if ((prev$i != current$i)); then
    echo "prev$i is $prev[i] and current$i is $current[i], they are different"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Use arrays instead.

Comment: You seem to partially be using array syntax already. You could just use arrays. If you describe what it is you're actually doing (what `prev` and `current` are), then we might be able to help you with an even better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you can use variable indirection

```bsh
    prev=prev$c
    current=current$c

    if ((${!prev} != ${!current})); then
        echo "prev$c is ${!prev} and current$c is ${!current}, they are different"
    fi
```

But using arrays is safer (no eval):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
number=0
for (( c=1; c<=2; c++ )) ; do
    prev[c]=$number
    number=$c
    current[c]=$number

    if ((${prev[c]} != ${current[c]})); then
        echo "prev$c is ${prev[c]} and current$c is ${current[c]}, they are different"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I have a feeling that if we were to be shown more of the user's code, it may well be enough with a single `prev` and a single `current` variable, possibly by swapping a couple of loops around.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes, I rarely use more than one $previous.